# How to interpret smoothing equation?

Tags: probability, bayesian-network, robotics

Sorry guys. This may be a basic question. I am doing a course on Robotics. I came across this equation for smoothing:

[image: Dynamic Bayesion Networks and (Full) SLAM]

Here, u -> control action, delta -> pose, z -> sensor measurement, l -> landmark

My question is:

How can I interpret this probability and in general any probability written as:

P(A, B| C, D)?

Is this:

1.) P((A and B) given (C and D))

2.) P(A and (B given C) and D)

3.) P(((A and B) given C) and D)

and so on.

Are any of these representations equivalent?? Thanks in advance.

Follow up question:

According to the Bayesian Net, the sensor measurement depends on where the robot is and the map. Isn't it more intuitive the other way around? Shouldn't the sensor's measurement dictate where the robot is and how the map is?

Comment: It's your option (1.)

Comment: Could you explain why, please? I'm really confused.

Comment: This is the standard notation for a conditional probability. $P(X\mid Y)=\frac{P(X,Y)}{P(Y)}$. Commas mean "and" in this notation. As to your followup question, the sensor measurement depends on the location and the map, since of course you sense different things at different locations and on different maps. It might be more natural to think of the information flowing the other way, but the statistical dependence goes both ways. In general, understanding a complicated Bayes net like this one requires very solid understanding of probability, especially conditional distributions and independence

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For typesetting, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).